# I assume SqlParameter.IsNullable only makes sense when…?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview, objectdatasource

1) When `SqlParameter.IsNullable` is set to `true`, received `null` value is converted to `DBNull.Value` and sent to database. Thus I would assume setting `IsNullable` to `true` only makes sense when GridView’s `Parameter.ConvertEmptyStringToNull` is also set to `true`?

2) Both GridView’s and ObjectDataSource’s parameters have a `ConvertEmptyStringToNull` property. But is there ever a situation where ( when trying to update data source ):

• where we should set GridView’s `Parameter.ConvertEmptyStringToNull` to `true`, but then set ObjectDataSource’s `Parameter.ConvertEmptyStringToNull` to `false`?!

• or where we should set GridView’s `Parameter.ConvertEmptyStringToNull` to `true`, but SqlDataSource’s `SqlParameter.IsNullable` to `false`?

Answer (score 0):

Ans : 1: When SqlParameter.IsNullable is set to true, received null value is converted to DBNull.Value and sent to database. Thus I would assume setting IsNullable to true only makes sense when GridView’s Parameter.ConvertEmptyStringToNull is also set to true? - simply yes

Answer (score 0):

The responses in general are "NO" to all your questions, because not always there is a DataGrid, which is not the only way to show data and or get an input from the user.

If your user interface provides data in another way (e.g. DetailView, FromView, hand-made-window-or-page, etc...), or you have not UI at all, and your data come from another source, you may have to deal with `IsNullable` and/or `ConvertEmptyStringToNull` properties independently from a DataGrid that does not exists!

`IsNullable` in particular, when you are calling stored procedures, should match the sp's definition of the parameter.