# SQL Parameter IsNullable

Tags: c#, sql, parameters

Through the SqlParameter class (for C#) I can see parameters in a stored procedure.

How do you know if a parameter is mandatory or not? I tried using IsNullable but it's always false.

Maybe I'm writing a wrong stored procedure, or is IsNullable meant just to set?

Thanks

Comment: NULLABLE is not the same as OPTIONAL.  You *can* have a non-optional but nullable field.  You can also have an optional non-nullable field.

Answer (score 2):

"Optional" simply means there is a default for stored procedure parameters.
Otherwise, *all* parameters can be NULL: there is no definition constraint to stop this.

You'd have to parse the stored proc T-SQL to see the default, as per this answer [Is there a solution for getting the default value of the parameters of a given stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6992561/27535)

And if you can parse the stored proc definition, then you start to lose the encapsulation benefits

Answer (score 0):

In Codebehind use this for checking whether database values are null or not

```
bool isnull = Convert.IsDBNull(yourvalue);
```

In SQL use [ISNULL (check_expression, replacement_value)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)

```
select ISNULL(columnname, 0) from tablename
```

Comment: It works for the resultset but here he wants to know if a parameter is mandatory. I don't think there's a way to known if a parameter is mandatory by code but I'm not 100% sure.